# Set <select> tag selected value in PHP

Tags: php, html

What would be the best way to set  tag selected value?

```
<select id="attr_field_10" name="config_eph_payment_type">
<option value="5">First</option>
<option value="1">Second</option>
<option value="2">Third</option>
<option value="3">Fourth</option>
<option value="4">Fifth</option>
<option value="7">Sixth</option>
</select>
```

The value comes from `$config_eph_payment_type` variable (5, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 7).

Comment: Show us the php which generates the tag.

Comment: @Deadalus, the tag is static html. Maybe would be better to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Unless you want to mess with ajax.. it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$options = array(
   5 => "First",
   1 => "Second",
   ...
   7 => "Sixth"
);


echo "<select id=\"attr_field_10\" name=\"config_eph_payment_type\">";

foreach ($options as $k => $v) {

    echo "<option value=\"$k\"";

    if ($k == $config_eph_payment_type) 
        echo " selected";

    echo ">$v</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

What we basically do is to store the options into an associative array. Then, we loop through it and keep checking if the value is equal to the variable `$config_eph_payment_type`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="5"<?php if ($config_eph_payment_type == 5) print ' selected="selected"'; ?>>First</option>
```

This is the easiest way to do it. You could also put the if at the beginning of the file and then define a variable, this would make the HTML code more readable

```
<?php
//at beginning
if ($config_eph_payment_type==5)
    $fiveSelected = ' selected="selected"';
else
    $fiveSelected = '';
?>
```

in your code
    First